# Que signifie le mot « revenir » dans la phrase « Il faut faire revenir des oignons à la poêle » ?

Tags: sens, lexique

Je suppose que « revenir » signifie « remettre dans la poêle ».

Est-ce correct ou vaut-il mieux utiliser le verbe « remettre » ?

Comment: C'est visuel : Coupez des oignons en petits morceaux et jetez-les dans une poêle chauffée avec une bonne huile. Si vous ne voulez pas que votre préparation brûle, vous saisissez le manche et en mouvements répétitifs, vous repoussez la poêle et la rapprochez de vous … et voyez votre nourriture glisser au plus loin de vous et *revenir* vers le manche. C'est un mouvement technique qui permet de retourner les monceaux d'oignons sur tous les côtés, ce qui permet de contrôler leur cuisson qui doit s'arrêter lorsqu'ils sont devenus translucides ou plus-ou-moins colorés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est un sens spécifique à la cuisine :

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/revenir) :

> **IV.**
> ...
> **B.** − *Usuel. Faire revenir de la viande, du poisson, des légumes, des oignons.* (Laisser) se colorer plus ou moins fortement, avant la cuisson proprement dite, une volaille, un poisson, un légume dans un corps gras fortement chauffé (d'apr. Courtine, *Gastr.* 1984). *Lapin sauté ! cria-t-il (...). Il « tomba la veste », alluma le poêle et fit « revenir » le lapin* (Dabit, *Hôtel Nord*, 1929, p. 145).V. aussi cari ex. Absol. (...) *Mettez ces légumes dans une casserole avec (...) cinq hectos de beurre; faites revenir d'une couleur rouge (Gdes heures cuis. fr.,*J. Gouffé, 1877, p. 183). *Je connaissais toutes les ragougnasses, toutes les manières de faire « revenir »* (Céline, *Mort à crédit*, 1936, p. 471).

Voir [expressio.fr](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/faire-revenir-une-viande-un-aliment#:%7E:text=Cette%20expression%20date%20du%20XVIIe,ramollit%20(qui%20reprend%20vie%20%3F)) pour l'origine supposée :

> Cette expression date du XVIIe siècle.
> Elle vient probablement du sens de 'revenir' dans "revenir à soi", ou "retrouver ses esprits, retrouver vie", comme après un évanouissement, par exemple.

En italien: *far rosolare* (rissoler).